# Ink Desktop functionality for someone with a seperate tablet?

Tags: windows-vista, desktop, tablet

[Ink Desktop](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fdownloads%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fdisplaylang%3Den%26FamilyID%3De1a51f4a-9e58-45f7-985b-3c37b8eedb71&ei=HPWASq3yL4rQM_LGpZ0L&rct=j&q=microsoft+ink+desktop&usg=AFQjCNHX7lc4kawYAtjERlAkr00-7fCkxg) is a program by microsoft that allows people with table PC's the ability to jot notes on their desktop background. I have a separate tablet and would also like to be able to draw on my desktop. Are there any programs anyone is aware of that will provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ink Desktop with separate tablet.

Wacoms tablets are absolutely supported.